# Adding a click event within a another function

Tags: jquery, click

This has been bugging me way too long. I am trying to create a click event within a function, which doesn’t seem to be working. Here is the basic layout:

```
function init() {

$('#a2').click(function() {
//does some stuff. Works fine.

    $('#addDest').click(function() {
    //does more stuff. Works fine…
        if ($("#input2").is(':visible'))     
        {alert("test");};
     });
});
};
```

The page is always assuming #input2 is visible! Even though it is switching on and off. I check in Firebug and it is able to know the truth. However, when I click on #input2, the alert ALWAYS pops up!
I could throw my problem part outside of the function. But that will create more problems – as I will have some undeclared variables when the document loads. I am thinking I made this the long way and maybe event handlers or clickevents are a solution for more. But I am not quite at that level of understanding yet. I know it is reading that problem area, as when the page loads. Is there an easier solution to this issue? I know I prolly need to learn more... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So, every time you click on `#a2`, you want to reset the click event functionality on `#addDest`? Is that necessary?

Comment: yea - bc #addDest is hidden is hidden unless #a2 was clicked first.

Comment: And there are some objects created in #a2 which I don't want if it wasn't clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this markup:

```
<button id="a2">A2</button>
<button id="addDest">Add</button>
<input type="text" id='input2'>
```

and this CSS:

```
#addDest,#input2{display:none;}
```

this works:

```
$('#a2').click(function() {
    $('#addDest').show();
});
$('#addDest').click(function() {
    if ($("#input2").is(':visible')) {
        alert("test");
    };
    $('#input2').show();
});
```

Explanation:

- Makes the the assumption that all the elements exist, even if hidden.
- Since it is hidden, you can add the click event for addDest outside the click event handler for a2, as it will not be clicked if it IS hidden to start.
- in my example, the input2 is initially hidden, so you only see the alert on the second click (I show it in the first click event handler for addDest.)

If you change the

```
  $('#input2').show();
```

to:

```
$('#input2').toggle();
```

you can see it change based on the visibility of the input.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/25Vfy/

Comment: Thanks! I think my problem was the ordering of my CSS and JS. But that example really showed how to get it right. Thanks sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be that the `click` event on #addDest is being bound over and over. Try doing a `$('#addDest').unbind("click")` before binding it

Comment: hmmm. I tried throwing that in every possible location and it usually just removes the click function process. I am just confused bc if I throw "$("#input2").is(':visible')" in Firefox, it will say "false" if it's hidden. But then when I click #addDest, it is still always showing the alert.

Answer (score 0):

you could attempt something like this

```
$('#a2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-clicked','true'); 
});


$('#addDest').live('click', function() {

    if ($("#input2").is(':visible') && $('#a2').attr('data-clicked') == 'true')     
    {alert("test");};
 });
```

if you want it to only alert the first time it is clicked

```
$('#a2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-clicked','true'); 
});

$('#addDest').live('click', function() {

    if ($("#input2").is(':visible') && $('#a2').attr('data-clicked') == 'true'){

           if($(this).attr('data-clicked') != 'true'){
              $(this).attr('data-clicked','true'); 
              alert("test");
           };
     }
});
```

Comment: it still is alerting me on every click. I am going to simplify my page and try these solutions without everything else I have going on. I'll let you know!

Comment: you want it to only alert one time?